# set Strikethough text in listView android

Tags: android, listview

i want to set strikethough in text when user click the checkbox inside the listView .Assume that i have three items inside the listView , but when i clicked the checkbox in first item , it only strikethough in text of last item .

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
        model = helper.getAllProduct(list);
        startManagingCursor(model);

        listView.setAdapter(new ShoppingListAdapter(this,model));
        class ShoppingListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context ,Cursor c) {
            super(context,R.layout.productrow,c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.produtName);
            final CheckBox listCheck=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
            listCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(listCheck.isChecked()){
                              listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                            //listName.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        //  listName.setText("go");
                        }
                    }

                  });
```

anybody know wat is my mistake ?

Comment: set the flag outside the onCheckedChange too, for ones that are already checked.

Comment: set flag outside? mean i setPaintFlag outside too ? sorry i am new in android programming ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lalit Poptani is correct it is because of recycling mechanism of listview. while scrolling the list , already created views will be reused.  while scrolling getview() method will be called. so u have to check whether check box is checked or not. if it is checked u have to set paint flag and not means you have to remove the paint flags.

```
if(isChecked){
    txtview.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
 }else{
    txtview.setPaintFlags( task_text.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
listName.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: ya ,it is work ..but when i click the checkbox in First item , it only setPaintFlag in last item .

Comment: I think that's problem due to final keyword with your checkbox.

Comment: i charged to private ..but the problem now is only can setPaintFlag in last item...first item nothing change.

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything with private, its a problem of final. The variable checkbox is overridden every time. Thats wrong, as you want different checkbox for each row.

Comment: Its happening because of recycling mechanism of ListView. So, shreya kindly look for the same.